# Simplifying Boolean algebra expression with two brackets

Tags: boolean, algebra, simplify, simplification

Could someone please show me how to get the answer? The correct answer is `c)`:

> Simplify the following Boolean algebraic expressions (where `’` means `not`):
>
> ```
> A.B’ + A.(B + C)’ + B.(B + C)’
> ```

```
a) B.C’
b) B + C
c) A.B’
d) A + B’
e) None of the above
```

Comment: what is ' supposed to mean?

Comment: @Gamopo sorry i forgot to mentinon that, it equivalent to NOT.

Comment: Are you sure that it is A.B’ + A.(B + C)’ + B.(B + C)’ instead of A.B’ + C.(B + C)’ + B.(B + C)’? I mean changing A for C in the second part?

Comment: @Gamopo Yeah i copied and pasted it exactly from the sheet. im so confused xD

Comment: Okay it totally checks now, I tell you in the answer

Answer (score 1):

First simplify the parentheses

```
A.B’ + A.(B + C)’ + B.(B + C)’=
A.B’ + A.B’.C’ + B.B’.C’
```

Now `B.B’=0` so the third term is gone:

```
A.B’ + A.B’.C’
```

Now you can regroup `A.B’`:

```
A.B’.(1 + C’)
```

Finally `1+C’=1` so all that's left is

```
A.B’
```